# How To Install Steam?

Tags: release-freya, steam

I'm getting the following errors:

> Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed
>
> Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 needs to be installed
>
> Package libc6:i386 needs to be installed
>
> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
>   libGL.so.1

Comment: can you add more details? how you tried to install steam?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workaround is

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386
```

Now run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install steam
```

*EDIT*:

First you need to configure a new foreign architecture to install `steam`.

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, `sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` #now this should return `i386`

Now continue above steps exactly.

**Note**:

Make sure `trusty-updates` is enabled in Software & Updates

[image: Imgur]

Comment: It says: "Package libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package. (...) However the following packages replace it: libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid"; "Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source"; E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386' has no installation candidate; E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386' has no installation candidate

Comment: I did `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and now I'm having: Unable to locate packages: `libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty` and `libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty`.

Comment: why you changed to trusty? run the exact commands. what is output of `uname -r`. btw how you tried to install `steam`? by using the terminal command?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed trusty and vivid. The workaround [gives this](http://i.imgur.com/yxHfNPx.png). `sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` returns i386. I installed by `sudo apt-get install steam`. Funny thing: `trusty-updates` unticks by itself after entering password!

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386 libqt5gui5 libcgmanager0 libudev1 libgl1 libgl-mesa-glx`  to      http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ . Also run `sudo apt-get install -f` and add output if you have any errors.

Comment: To Mod: Please move this discussion to chat. @RolandiXor♦

Comment: [here's the output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14476846/). `uname -r` gives "3.19.0-43-generic" and `sudo apt-get install -f` gives "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded".

Comment: Now run: `sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 steam` and let me know :)

Comment: I'm sorry. [Unsuccessful](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14477917/). What if I reinstall elementary OS?

Comment: I surprised, [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14476846/) you have `libcgmanager0`  . Please run: [commands](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14488264/) and let me know

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent version of Elementary (6, Odin) I installed Steam using the Flatpak version and it worked well. The problem was that when I wanted to use Steam Play (trying to emulate Windows using Proton) my game wouldn't launch (I was trying to play The Secret of Monkey Island Special Edition.

It turns out Proton doesn't really play well with the Flatpak version of Steam, so I had to install Steam from the official .deb on https://store.steampowered.com/about/.

Installing via the .deb (I used Eddy) leaves a bunch of dependencies out. Here's what worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

And for the 32-bit drivers

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
sudo apt-get libgl1:i386 libdrm2:i386
```

I hope this helps anyone trying to install Steam in 2021.

Answer (score -1):

Download and install the latest drivers from NVIDIA. During the NVIDIA driver installation it asks if you want to install the 32bit libraries. Select yes.

Comment: My graphics is: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b). It would work?