# Steam Installing but not running

Tags: steam

I've tried installing steam using the `.deb` file from their webpage and ran into the same problem found [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3899/how-to-install-steam). I got rid of the problem as described, but when trying to launch steam nothing happens, and I can't even launch it from terminal.

I then tried to install it using the command line apt-get (I even tried using aptitude), and although these don't give me any errors, nothing happens when I try run steam.

I purged steam between each attempt, and even deleted the `.steam` folder which doesn't seem to delete when steam is purged.

I have the latest Nvidia drivers installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I now get the following when running steam from command line.

```
:~$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2016-04-23 12:54:29] Startup - updater built Nov 25 2013 18:07:05
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Comment: Could be your GPU drivers. What is your GPU

Comment: @SuiciDoga I have a Nvidia gtx 970, with the latest drivers. I read somewhere that I may need to use the latest stable version, but not sure how to uninstall custom installed drivers.

Comment: Install steam from appcentre directly. There's no need for a deb file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing xfonts required to launch steam. You can install them with  `sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi`. Then log out, log back in, and launch steam again.

If that fails try `sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi` or `sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi-scalable`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing steam from app center built into elementary! Just search steam and hit the free button.

Comment: This thread is two years old. But thanks. At the time app center didn't exist.